# xelatex could not find MinionPro.sty

Tags: xetex, font-encodings, minionpro, texlive-2018

I have installed Minion Pro fonts followed this post https://kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2012/11/10/installing-minion-pro/.

And I ended up compiling `mnsymbol-test.tex` and `minionpro-test.tex` successfully with pdflatex. But if I tried compiling minionpro-test.tex with XeLaTeX, I faced the following error:

> Latex Error: File 'MinionPro.sty' not found.

It seems that xelatex fails to find where MinionPro.sty is located. Anyone knows how to fix this? I'm using `texlive-2018`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Excuse me, I hope. Can you put, please, the full minimal code to compile it? If it possible to add also the .log file. Thanks.

Comment: There is no reason why pdflatex should find a sty but xelatex not -- if both  engines are from the same texsystem. But the installation is only useful for pdflatex anyway. With xelatex you should load the fonts with fontspec.